# Set my location is not working in my app

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

```
try{
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // set my location
    }

mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); //Enables button
```

I have this essentials to visualize my location in android studio, but when I open the emulator, it appears the location button but it doesn't show location once I press on it.

I have also added the location permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Is there any suggestion that you could provide with this simple issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the targetSdk of your app, and what version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 26, minSdkVersion is 19 and 8.0.0 for Android

Comment: Take a look at the linked duplicate, there is a fully working solution in the answer there.

Comment: Yes, all of that is done! So it has to be something else.